# How to get a variable value from sh file and pass it in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a sh file which fetches the username and password. i want to pass this as a parameter to another shell script. How do i do that

```
fetch_credentials.sh
export user=test
export pass=test123

bash
./fetch_credentials.sh
echo "userName : "$user
echo "password : "$pass
```

i'm presently getting null values when i execute the same.

Comment: It won't help if you execute that script in a child process. You need to run it inside the current process (i.e. sourcing the script). Alternatively, `fetch_credentials.sh` could write the values into a file and your script could read them back from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *source* your first file, as:

```sh
$ cat > fetch_credentials.sh
export user=test
export pass=test123

$ source fetch_credentials.sh 

$ echo "userName: $user, password: $pass"
userName: test, password: test123
```

Note that source is an alias for `.` so you can also use `. fetch_credentials.sh`.